# How to add caves to a terrain mesh generated with 2D noise

Tags: unity, procedural-generation

Am I getting it right, that when I'll make a single mesh that represents terrain using unity's built-in 2D Perlin noise function, then I'll be able to somehow add caves using whatever (Perlin worms for example)?

Or do I need to find solution with 3d noise?

Comment: It sounds like you have a plan for how to make your terrain, enough to get started on building it. What specific obstacle have you encountered when trying to do this that we can help you overcome?

Comment: I'll give more specific info about what I'm trying to do: procedural voxel terrain like Minecraft or Cube World put in single mesh. And use for that perlin noise. Unity has a built in Mathf.PerlinNoise function BUT it is 2D. If I use it for my voxel terrain, will I somehow be able to dig caves through my terrain and if yes - how, if no - what I should do then?

Comment: It sounds like you have not made an attempt to implement this yet, and are asking us to vet your idea for you. That's not something we will do. Just implement your idea. If when you try to do it you encounter a problem, ask for a solution to that specific problem. There isn't any obvious obstacle here: you use the 2D noise function to decide a surface height, then you apply your cave generation method of choice to tunnel out cavities where you like under that surface threshold. If you hit a blocker when you try to implement that, be explicit about the problem so we can help you solve it.

Comment: This is not problem-solution forum anywhere in its topic. Why should I have an obvious blocker to ask a question? Lol. I have a very specific question and if you don't have an answer, why ever you reply? The question is very obvious and targets people who know the subject well, the people who tried to do what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: If you read carefully, I did answer: yes you can do this. The reason we need a specific blocker is that it's unclear what is stopping you. We're happy to help you solve such a problem, but right now there is no problem in evidence, so we can't say more than "yes, you can use Perlin noise to set the terrain height and Perlin worms to dig under it" which is too short to be a good answer.

Comment: If in your opinion 100500 letters is better than 10 clear words, I have no more questions for you.

Comment: Your question is not "very specific", it is very general. You basically asked "Can I make terrain with 2D perlin noise and then add caves?" DMGregory answered "There isn't any obvious obstacle here", which could be shortened to "Probably". A specific question would be along the lines of "I've written this code but now I'm stuck on this specific part", or "I've written this code but line 25 doesn't work right and I'm not sure why."

Comment: No I didn't ask what you've said, learn to read then judge. The question is for people WHO TRIED EXACTLY THIS already. Don't be silly. If you're interested, there's Reddit thread and Unity forum post where I asked exactly the same and got normal replies that solved my question, while you two keep trying to find "specific obstacles":

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/lrkufb/small_question_about_procedural_terrain_generation/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

https://forum.unity.com/threads/small-question-about-procedural-terrain-generation.1064156/#post-6876236

Comment: To add, I'm so dissatisfied by this forum that I'll never ask a question there anymore since there I encounter only unnecessary bulls*** that say my question is wrong.